# Chrome: transform scale doesn't work in combination with filter blur while unrelated element is using transform with transition

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions, css-animations

I have a picture that I am using with `filter: blur(16px); transform: scale(1.3);`. Above that I have a div with `overflow: hidden`. And then there is a completely unrelated element on the site on which I use `transform: scale(1.15); transition: all 1s;`.

Now the problem is, when the transition of the unrelated element is active (by saying unrelated I mean it is nowhere near the other element), the other element falls back to scale(1) until the transition is done. This problem only occurs in Google Chrome. Both Firefox and Safari are completely fine.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Even if this is just a patch to work around a bug in Chrome, an actual example that demonstrates the issue will help future visitors who have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found a workaround. No idea why this works, but after toying around with `z-index` a little I was able to fix this on Chrome as well. I just gave the element with `overflow: hidden` a `z-index: 2` and that worked. Gotta love CSS.